# How should I write code for this scenario in laravel

Tags: laravel, service

i Have marks and result attribute in my table where if a students gets >55 the result should be passed and if not then fail. How should I write the code

Comment: I will recommend you to try something and if you have any problems then post them here. Most SO users will recommend you the same, this will help you get better answers and better points. Good luck

Comment: You are a new contributor so could you please provide more clarity on the question.